# Parent event doesn't work

Tags: html, events

I have a **label** element for an input file which has the default click event to open a file selection dialog. this is for image uploading.after upload, the uploaded image is shown inside the label and if the user wants to change the photo he/she clicks the photo(or the buttons-child elements) and the dialog reopens. my problem is that after image uploading, if the user clicks on image the dialog won't open **in IE 8**(default parent label event).here is my code:

```
<label class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput" style="cursor: pointer;width: 200px;">
    <input type="file" name="photo_2" style="position: absolute;left:-9999px">
    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 130px;background:url(http://localhost/project/assets/images/upload_a_photo.png) no-repeat center center;cursor: pointer">
    <img width="190px" height="116px" src="http://localhost/project/uploads/394230a6519aae0d21170d6a409e5010.jpg">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Default</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Primary</button>
</label>
```

**JSBIN:**

http://jsbin.com/uXequYa/1

It must not contain any JS code for calling parent event because IE prevents changing input value though that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
<label for="ID_OF_YOUR_INPUT_EL" ...
```

and

```
<input  type="file" id="ID_OF_YOUR_INPUT_EL" ...
```

Comment: I've done it earlier and no luck. sorry for my code not containing id and for attributes.

Comment: Its strange.. I don't have IE8 to test but this is default. Hm... maybe you should check one more time?